# Java Spring - Append values from a form submission to a backend API call

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

Let's say that I have a front-end service, written in Java Spring, which serves a simple static HTML form.

```
<form action="/endpoint" method="get">
    <input type="text" id="firstName">
    <input type="text" id="lastName">
</form>
```

And I have a back-end service, also written in Java, that calls an external API like so:

```
public static JsonObject getCall(String firstName, String lastName) {
    JsonObject response = externalApi.get("http://api.example.com/endpoint?first_name="+firstName+"&last_name="+lastName);
    return JsonObject;
}
```

How would I write my controller in my front-end service such that it's able to pass the data along?

Comment: Check this https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/spring/mvc/spring-mvc-form-handling-example/

Comment: you can create rest controller